# How to Remove ContextMenu in CKEditor 4.3

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am having a hard time trying to disable the context menu from the editor. For instance when a user clicks on a image I don't want to show that context menu but the browser context.

I tried to add to remove plugins configuration setting "contextmenu" but that did nothing. From the posts I seen here the soultion to get rid of the context menu seems to change every version.

Answer (score 2):

Tested in Ckeditor `4.7.1`, works for me:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
  config.language = 'en';
  config.toolbar = "mini";
  config.removePlugins = 'elementspath,contextmenu,liststyle,tabletools,tableselection';
  config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was always the same:

```
config.removePlugins = 'contextmenu,tabletools';
```

And I don't know any situation in which this does not work. See an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/xay4E/).

PS. Disabling CKEditor's context menu isn't recommended.

**EDIT:** My fault, I haven't checked the console. To remove the `contextmenu` plugin I first need to remove `tabletools` which requires the first one. So I updated an example - see http://jsfiddle.net/xay4E/4/. When you can't disable some plugin, because of requirements, an error is logged on the console.

Comment: This does not work in all cases. See that it is possible to bring the paste content menu in FF: http://screencast.com/t/8AchAxLEo

Comment: I also get this, when I add a picture and right click on it. The context menu comes up in FF

Comment: Wow... I see this and I'm really shocked :D. Definitely a bug. I'll let you know when I find something.